# When a variable is updating in reactjs, And how to force the update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to understand,
i know when i console.log(pictures) i get the end result

and when i "console.log(JSON.stringify(pictures))" i get the current one at that moment.

why does in that moment when it logs the second option, the array is empty
and in the end it got a value,

how can i force the synchronization  of the value and this.state

the problem is that when i am sending in the end:

> ImageList pics={this.state.picturesArr} />

it is being sent empty

```
let pictures = [];
let urls =[];
let titles=[];
let nextpage ='';
let pageback='';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            picturesArr: [],
            urlArr: [],
            titleArr:[],
            nextPage:'',
            prevuisPage:''
        };

        this.loadSubreddit = this.loadSubreddit.bind(this);
    }

    loadSubreddit(subre) {

        reddit.hot(subre).limit(5).fetch(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
            nextpage = res.data.after.toString();
            // pageback = res.data.before.valueOf();

            for (let i = 0; i < res.data.children.length; i++){
                pictures.push(res.data.children[i].data.url);
                urls.push(res.data.children[i].data.permalink);
                titles.push(res.data.children[i].data.title);
            }
        });

        this.setState({
            picturesArr: pictures,
            urlArr: urls,
            titleArr: titles,
            nextPage: nextpage,
            prevuisPage: pageback
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state)
        });

        console.log(pictures);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(pictures));
    }


    componentWillMount() {
        console.log('comp is mounting');
        this.loadSubreddit('cats');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
            <div className="App-header">
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
            </div>
                <Col sm={8} md={10} smOffset={2} mdOffset={1} >
                    <ImageList pics={this.state.picturesArr} />
                </Col>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) you are trying to use async result in synchronous way. That is not possible. You need to call setState inside callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you provided, you call `this.setState` outside of the api-call callback.

You need to (1) move the code for setting state inside the callback, and (2) bind the callback function to the component instance to access its `this.setState`.

The fixed `loadSubbreddit` function is shown below.

```js
loadSubreddit(subre) {

    reddit.hot(subre).limit(5).fetch(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        nextpage = res.data.after.toString();
        // pageback = res.data.before.valueOf();

        for (let i = 0; i < res.data.children.length; i++){
            pictures.push(res.data.children[i].data.url);
            urls.push(res.data.children[i].data.permalink);
            titles.push(res.data.children[i].data.title);
        }

        this.setState({
            picturesArr: pictures,
            urlArr: urls,
            titleArr: titles,
            nextPage: nextpage,
            prevuisPage: pageback
        }, () => {
            console.log(this.state)
        });

        console.log(pictures);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(pictures));
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Correct. And now  `pictures` doesn't have to be a global variable.

Comment: Thanks! so just to make sure i got my mistake,
when using this.setState it needs to be with in the api callback(i need to read a bit more about it),
and because another execution context is created for the inner function i need to bind "this", so it will point to the existing state

Comment: When making api-calls in general, you need to wait for the response before you can store it. You can also use `setState` outside api-call callbacks, but not if you want to wait for the response from an api-call.